# Having a report display everything from a form

Tags: ms-access

So I have a combo box on my form, and depending on what is selected, the query filters the info and runs the report and displays that info. What I would like to do is have the report display everything when the combo box is left blank. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Posting sample code would help, but here is a general answer.
I assume your query filter looks something like this:

```
SELECT Stuff From Table Where MyField = MyComboBox
```

If that is the case, you can do the following:

```
SELECT Stuff From Table Where (MyField = MyComboBox) OR NZ(MyComboBox, "") = ""
```

If either your combo box us set to nothing or an empty string, you will get the full result.